# Rails: Serve compressed static assets from Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Rails 4 and my app is deployed to Heroku.

I'm trying to serve compressed assets from Cloudfront. Cloudfront's distribution origin points to Amazon S3, where the compressed version of js and css are present.

However, these compressed assets are not being served by Cloudfront. I've read that gems like `heroku-deflater` and `rack-zippy work`, but these will serve the assets from Heroku, as opposed to serving them from Cloudfront. In other words, I need my `config.serve_static_assets` to be `false`, as I want Heroku not to serve the assets.

How can I serve the compressed assets?

Answer (score 0):

Why not server them from Heroku? Hear me out:

Create a Cloudfront Distribution that has the Heroku's app url as origin. Then just set `config.asset_host = 'http://abcd12345678.cloudfront.net'`. This way Cloudfront gets hit, and if it doesn't have the compressed asset, it asks Heroku for it. Essentially, Heroku will server the assets only once (to CloudFront)